# Removing vowels from string

Tags: c

I've been trying to do this function where the target is to remove the vowels of a string. **This is what I have :**

```
void
take_vowels (char s[])
{
  int i;
  char r[4];

  for (i = 0; i <= strlen (s); i++)
    {
      if (s[i] == 'a' || s[i] == 'e' || s[i] == 'i' || s[i] == 'o'
          || s[i] == 'u')
        {
          r[i] = ' ';
        }
      else
        {
          r[i] = s[i];
        }
    }
  printf ("%s\n", r);
}

int
main ()
{
  char s[4] = { 'a', 'e', 'k', };
  take_vowels (s);
  return 0;
}
```

This seems to work fine but **I want to know if there is a better way to do this function**. Any suggestions?

Comment: Upper case?  Length other than 3?  Not recomputing strlen every time through?  Abstract test to a function isVowel?  Minor comments.

Comment: As written, this only works on strings up to 3 bytes long.  `r` should be `malloced` or alternatively, passed in as an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your title says 'remove vowels from the string', but in fact you are replacing the vowels by a space.

You don't need to do `strlen` at all. You just need to remember that your string is (by definition) already large enough, and it is a sequence of characters. Also a `switch` statement is nicer than a large `if`, and you presumably want to handle both cases.

It's also normal to take a `char *s` as an argument rather than a `char s[]`. Look at every string function in the standard library! Similarly, the normal way to initialize C strings is:

```
char *s = "aek";
```

not

```
char s[4] = { 'a', 'e', 'k', };
```

Here's two (untested) functions which will help:

```
#include <ctype.h>

...

void 
replacevowelsbyspace (char *s)
{
    for (; *s; s++)
    {
        switch (tolower (*s))
        {
            case 'a':
            case 'e':
            case 'i':
            case 'o':
            case 'u':
                *s = ' ';
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
#include <ctype.h>

...

void 
deletevowels (char *s)
{
    char *d = s;
    for (; *s; s++)
    {
        switch (tolower (*s))
        {
            case 'a':
            case 'e':
            case 'i':
            case 'o':
            case 'u':
                break;
            default:
                *d++ = *s;
        }
    }
    *d = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your function is that it has undefined behaviour because the source array can have more than 4 characters. 
The function does not remove vowels from the source string. It copies the source string in a local array replacing vowels with spaces.

So the function does not do what was announced.

Comment: Instead of creating the new array r , I just use s? How can I remove the vowels?
I'm really new at C  sorry :P

Comment: @José Cunha Simply copy the array into itself skipping vowels.

Answer (score 0):

```
int vowel(char ch)
{
if((ch=='a'||ch=='e'||ch=='i'||ch=='o'||ch=='u')||
(ch=='A'||ch=='E'||ch=='I'||ch=='O'||ch=='U'))
return 1;
else 
return 0;
}

void removevowel(char str[])
{
 int count=0,i=0;
 while(str[i]!='\0')
  {
    if(!vowel(str[i]))
     {str[count++]=str[i];}
     i++;
  }
     str[count]='\0';
}

int main()
{
 char str[]="stAck overflOw SamplE";
 removevowel(str);
 for(int j=0; str[j]; j++)
 cout<<str[j];
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you add some text to explain this & how it resolves the OP's question?